# APP/API creation for page in Facebook Business manager?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to business manager as all of the pages I manage I have created myself. I have said I will look after a page for someone and they have granted me access, thus the page appears in my Business manager and I can make changes.

What I need to do is create an App/API connection to link the page to the website, is there anyway to do that without logging in through the customer's personal account or asking the customer to create the app?

The App needs to allow the website to autopost status updates.

Regards
Donna

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/bestpractice

Answer (score 1):

For posting status updates with the API, you need to do the following:

- Authorize someone who can post "as Page" with the `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` permission
- Get the Page ID with the following API call: `/page-id?fields=access_token`
- Post by using the resulting Page Token with this endpoint: `/page-id/feed`

...of course you need an App for that.

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: I understand how to post as I do wit with many of my sites, what I am asking is how to set up the App for a page I do not own, but have been given Page Admin rights in Business manager. I need to be able to generate the App ID/Secret/Access token to allow me to link the app to the website, and thus post directly.

Comment: the process should be the same, did you check if the page shows up with the /me/accounts endpoint?

Comment: Ok, i think i have it sorted. I could just create it from my personal account and once validated in the website I was able to choose which page I wanted to post to....Highly confusing having to link a business account to a personal account if you ask me. Thank you for your prompts :)